# AppArmor Error: "invalid VM definition" after starting lxc on updated version of libvirt (1.2.12)

Tags: virtualization, openstack, lxc, apparmor

I am trying to start an LXC on a newer version of libvirtd but it fails to start with the following error:

```
$ virsh -c lxc: start textlxc
error: Failed to start domain testlxc
error: internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-dfb2c573-05cb-4ca3-9e46-bea6cebf0f9f'
```

Error message in */var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log*

```
2015-06-23 12:13:12.306+0000: 14141: error : virCommandWait:2532 : internal error: Child process (/usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper -p 0 -c -u libvirt-dfb2c573-05cb-4ca3-9e46-bea6cebf0f9f) unexpected exit status 1: virt-aa-helper: error: /proc/meminfo
virt-aa-helper: error: skipped restricted file
virt-aa-helper: error: invalid VM definition

2015-06-23 12:13:12.306+0000: 14141: error : AppArmorGenSecurityLabel:468 : internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-dfb2c573-05cb-4ca3-9e46-bea6cebf0f9f'
```

This is my *testlxc.xml* file

```
<domain type='lxc'>
  <name>testlxc</name>
  <uuid>dfb2c573-05cb-4ca3-9e46-bea6cebf0f9f</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4048292</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4048292</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64'>exe</type>
    <init>/sbin/init</init>
  </os>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_lxc</emulator>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <source dir='/var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/testlxc'/>
      <target dir='/'/>
    </filesystem>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <source dir='/var/lib/libvirt/filesystems/testlxc-data'/>
      <target dir='/mnt/data'/>
    </filesystem>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <source dir='/var/run/testlxc/lxc'/>
      <target dir='/mnt/run'/>
    </filesystem>
    <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
      <source dir='/proc/meminfo'/>
      <target dir='/proc/meminfo'/>
    </filesystem>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='lxc' port='0'/>
      <alias name='console0'/>
    </console>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Libvirt version running is 1.2.12, I had been running the lxc succesfully on version 1.2.2 before.

```
$ libvirtd --version
libvirtd (libvirt) 1.2.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tracked down the problem to domain XML validation in `virt-aa-helper` utility. This is the utility which is supposed to generate apparmor profiles on demand. It is not the structure of the XML that fails, but the reported error seems to indicate that this is the case. A logical validation inside the function `virDomainDefParseXML` function in `domain_conf.c` is broken for LXC containers.

I am not familiar enough with libvirt code to modify this shared area - I may have broken something else, but the following patch seems to work:

```
if (!(flags & VIR_DOMAIN_DEF_PARSE_SKIP_OSTYPE_CHECKS)) {
    /* If the logic here seems fairly arbitrary, that's because it is :)
     * This is duplicating how the code worked before
     * CapabilitiesDomainDataLookup was added. We can simplify this,
     * but it would take a bit of work because the test suite fails
     * in numerous minor ways. */
    bool use_virttype = ((def->os.arch == VIR_ARCH_NONE) ||
        !def->os.machine);
    virCapsDomainDataPtr capsdata = NULL;
```

to read

```
if (!(flags & VIR_DOMAIN_DEF_PARSE_SKIP_OSTYPE_CHECKS)) {
    /* If the logic here seems fairly arbitrary, that's because it is :)
     * This is duplicating how the code worked before
     * CapabilitiesDomainDataLookup was added. We can simplify this,
     * but it would take a bit of work because the test suite fails
     * in numerous minor ways. */
    bool use_virttype = (def->os.type != VIR_DOMAIN_OS_TYPE_EXE) &&
        ((def->os.arch == VIR_ARCH_NONE) ||
          !def->os.machine);
    virCapsDomainDataPtr capsdata = NULL;
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to fix this without a recompile. If you use a 64-bit machine, you can download packages I've built locally from [this link](http://1drv.ms/1GFTDdS) (excuse my Microsoft account).

*Note*: To see if you are affected by this bug, enter the following in a command prompt (copied from [this forum post](http://tinyurl.com/nmabnd3)):

```
$ export VM=foo ; virsh -c lxc:// dumpxml $VM |\
   sudo /usr/lib/libvirt/virt-aa-helper -c \
   -u libvirt-`virsh -c lxc:// domuuid $VM`
```

Where `foo` is the name of the lxc container that fails. If you see the output

```
virt-aa-helper: error: could not parse XML
virt-aa-helper: error: could not get VM definition
```

then probably it is the same bug.